# Why does using ng-repeat to iterate html fail when the html contains divs?

Tags: angularjs

When I use ng-repeat to iterate the following code, everything is fine:

```
<p ng-repeat="user in users">
    <input size="50" ng-model="user.name"></input>
    <span>Foo</span>
</p>
```

However, using the following fails:

```
<p ng-repeat="user in users">
    <input size="50" ng-model="user.name"></input>
    <div>Foo</div>
</p>
```

In the latter case, it looks like the div is excluded from the loop and appended only once after the input tags that have been repeated as expected.

I'm trying to understand the difference in behaviour towards div tags.

Thanks for any insights.

EDIT: The question was already answered, but here's a js-fiddle that allowed me to demonstrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/f26Cg/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot nest `<div>` elements in `<p>` element: as shown [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/p.html), it's permitted to contain so-called [phrasing content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) only.

As `<div>` opening tag is considered to be an end of `<p>` element, technically its corresponding element is outside of `<p>` in the second case - that's why it's not repeated.

Answer (score 1):

I'll quote Josh's answer to this question : [Directive inside ng-repeat only appears once](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/tjYYRAJ6hyQ)

It is actually related to how your browser will handle blocks inside a non-allowing blocks tag.

> I imagine this is the browser's doing. Technically, paragraph tags are
>   only allowed to contain inline elements, which div is not. Some
>   browsers (most?) will automatically close the `<p>` when hits an
>   unauthorized tag. If you inspect the DOM, you will see that even the
>   div that makes it into the DOM from the ngRepeat is not inside the
>   generated paragraph.
>
> Josh